# validation In symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-1.4

I want validation in my Form ,Only Integer Numbers are allowed .
I am writing this code .. But it's Not Working .

```
     'value'=> new sfValidatorOr(array(
      new sfValidatorAnd(array(

          new sfValidatorRegex(array('pattern' => '/\d+/')),

      )))),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with "/^[\d]+$/" or  "/^[0-9]+$/" instead of "/\d+/".